# Redirect www to non-www only for https://

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't seem to find a nice way to redirect `https://www.x.co.uk` to `https://x.co.uk` whilst letting `http://x.co.uk` and `http://www.x.co.uk` keep whatever they want.

Could anyone lend a hand?

I have tried various things, the closest I think I have got is a straight up check like this;

```
    RewriteCond ^https://www\.x\.co\.uk/$ [NC]
    RewriteRule https://x.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't seem to match (or if it is it is ignoring the rewrite rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.x\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://x\.co\.uk$1 [L,R=301]
```

This is redirect someone from https://www.x.co.uk to https://x.co.uk and not do anything if they are no on https.